# Firebase Database Count

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What is the best way to add a count to your chat messages to upload to googles firebase database? The way I have it the count keeps geting re-initialized so it messes up the data.

**QUESTION:** What is the best way to upload chat messages so that they do not interfere with each other? via firebase.

+general_room
  1,2,3,4

numbers representing each messaga sent.

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

var count = 0

func UploadGeneralChatRoom(message : String) {

    //Firebase Initialization
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    //var storage: FIRStorageReference!
    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    //storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference()


    //Get Data from database resend to database
    ref.child("Users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

        let snapDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let username = snapDict?["Username"] as? String ?? ""
        let firebaseUserPhotoURL = snapDict?["photo_url"] as? String ?? ""

        count = count + 1
        print("Count: ", count)


        let countString = String(count)

        print("CountStrig: " + countString)


        ref.child("general_room").child(countString).setValue(["Username": username, "uid": userID!, "Message" : message, "photo_url" : firebaseUserPhotoURL])


    })

}
```

Comment: I'm having a really difficult time understanding the question. You are asking about adding a count, but then are also asking about chat messages interfering with each other? Also, the code is questionable as it initializes count to 0 and then you read and write some data to the database. Wouldn't it make more sense to read the count of the child nodes from firebase instead of starting at 0 every time? Please clarify and update the question and we'll try to answer.

Comment: my problem is having a new count each message. What im doing isnt working because im re-initializing to zero every time. I dont know how to modify my firebase upload so it never repeats the count and so That i have conistant message flow.

Comment: how would i count the node each time?

Comment: Your code doesn't count any new messages at all. It captures all the messages at /Users/userID all at a one time and there's no code to actually count the messages that were read in. It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish; do you want to keep a count of the number of messages in a node and then increment that counter when a new message is added? Or something else?

Comment: or for better words what would be the proper way to upload chat room messages to firebase database.

Comment: all im trying to do is upload a chat rooms messages with the user info attached to it. I dont know the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original question is pretty unclear but if you want to upload a message to a chat room, here's a structure:

```
users
  uid_0
   name: "Kirk"
  uid_1
   name: "Spock"
  uid_2
   name: "McCoy"

chat_rooms
  room_0
   name: "Bridge Chat Room"
   messages:
     message_0:
       msg: "This is a message posted by Spock"
       uid: "uid_1"
     message_1:
       msg: "Message posted by Kirk"
       uid: "uid_0"
```

and some code to create a new message in chat_rooms, room_0 (this could be greatly condensed but leaving verbose for readability)

```
let ref = rootRef.child("chat_rooms")
let roomRef = ref.child("room_0")
let messagesRef = roomRef.child("messages")
let msgRef = messagesRef.childByAutoId()
let data = ["msg": "a message posted by McCoy",
            "uid": "uid_2"]
msgRef.setValue(data)
```

will result in

```
chat_rooms
  room_0
   name: "Bridge Chat Room"
   messages:
     message_0:
       msg: "This is a message posted by Spock"
       uid: "uid_1"
     message_1:
       msg: "Message posted by Kirk"
       uid: "uid_0"
     message_2:
       msg: "a message posted by McCoy"
       uid: "uid_2"
```

message_0, message_1 etc are keys created with childByAutoId.

If you want to know how many messages there are, here's one option

```
messagesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    print(snapshot.childrenCount)
})
```

and the result

```
3
```